# jquery add to variable in loop

Tags: jquery, variables

I am trying to add to a variable and get the total price at the end of the loop and add it to a value in a span tag and update it. I am unsure how to do with jquery, I usualy do it with php. This is what I have tried but I get nothing.

```
$.each(data, function(key, obj) {
    items.push('<li id="' + obj.id + '">' + obj.title + '€' + obj.price + '</li>');
    totalprice += obj.price
});

$("#addonPrice").html($("#addonPrice").text() + totalprice);
```

Comment: Did you add "var totalprice = 0;" before the call to each()? And also, is obj.price a string or a number?

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the data object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var totalprice = 0;

$.each(data, function(key, obj){
    items.push('<li id="' + obj.id + '">' + obj.title + '€' + obj.price + '</li>');
    totalprice = totalprice + parseFloat(obj.price);
});
$('#addonPrice').html(parseFloat($('#addonPrice').text()) + totalprice);
```

You need to initialize the total price and convert the price / addon price to a float to work with them as numbers.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You should initialize `totalprice` to zero before the loop as well as apply `parseFloat()` to `obj.price` before adding it:

```
var totalprice = 0;
$.each(data, function(key, obj) {
    items.push('<li id="' + obj.id + '">' + obj.title + '€' + obj.price + '</li>');
    totalprice += parseFloat(obj.price);
});
$("#addonPrice").html(parseFloat($("#addonPrice").text()) + totalprice);
```

Answer (score 3):

try this :

```
totalprice += parseInt(obj.price);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things about this. First you haven't shown where and how is the `totalprice` variable being initialized. Normally this should be done outside of the loop. Secondly depending on the type of `obj.price`, the `+=` operator you are using might perform string concatenations instead of number additions. Also the `.text` function returns a string so you need to cast it to a number when performing the addition at the end of the loop:

```
var totalprice = 0;
$.each(data, function(key, obj) {
    items.push('<li id="' + obj.id + '">' + obj.title + '€' + obj.price + '</li>');
    totalprice += Number(obj.price);
});

$("#addonPrice").html(parseFloat($("#addonPrice").text()) + totalprice);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate `totalprice` before the loop as the totalprice will cease to exist out of the context of `$.each`.